# Не открывать необъявленные виртуальные хосты

Tags: linux, apache

Добрый день.

На компе Win стоит виртуальная машина, на ней развернута CentOS 6.6 (minimal) + Apache. 
Также на ней статический IP 192.168.1.15.

Основной конфигурационный файл `/etc/conf/httpd.conf` не тронут, и в нем нет объявления виртуальных хостов.

В отдельном конфигурационном файле `/etc/conf.d/virt.conf` объявлены два виртуальных хоста:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    ServerName site1.test.ru
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/server.crt
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    ServerName site2.test.ru
</VirtualHost>
```

На основной физической машине с Win в файле hosts прописаны:

```
192.168.1.15 site1.test.ru
192.168.1.15 site2.test.ru
```

При попытке зайти с основном физической машины на http://site1.test.ru попадаю в каталог  /var/www/html/site1

При попытке зайти с основном физической машины на https://site2.test.ru попадаю в каталог  /var/www/html/site2

При попытке зайти с основном физической машины на **http://site2.test.ru** попадаю в каталог  **/var/www/html/site1** (Чего не должно быть!)

При попытке зайти с основном физической машины на **http://192.168.1.15** попадаю в каталог  **/var/www/html/site1** (Чего не должно быть!)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут дело и как его решить?

Спасибо.

Comment: В дефолтном хосте. Сервер долен отдать хоть что-нибудь, поэтому он отдает дефолтный хост в случае, если хост не может быть определен явно. Если дефолтный хост не задан явно, то им является первый объявленный хост. Поэтому можно встретить 000-default.conf, который автоматом подгружается раньше остальных

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что необходимо прописать в 000-default.conf?

Comment: Все, разобрался, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Когда Вы набираете `http://site2.test.ru` - идет обработка директив виртуальных хостов, начинающих с `<VirtualHost *:80>`, так как выбран протокол HTTP, работающий по 80 порту.

Если Вы наберете http**s**://site2.test.ru, то попадете в `/var/www/html/site2`.

Чтобы сделать `/var/www/html/site2` для всех протоколов, замените директиву `<VirtualHost *:443>` на `<VirtualHost *:*>`